# Rails 3 has_many :through Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Can't figure out why this is not working.  First time using :has_many => :through

Keep getting `uninitialized constant User::Employmentship`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employmentships
  has_many :companies, :through => :employmentships
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employmentships, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |obj| obj.blank? }
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :firstname, :lastname, :username,  :role, :company_ids
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employmentships
  has_many :users, :through => :employmentships
end


/views/users/_form.html.erb
<p>
   <%= for company in Company.all do %>
     <%= check_box_tag "user[company_ids][]", company.id, @user.companies.include?(company) %>
     <%= company.name%>
   <% end %>
</p>
```

EDIT - If I change @user.companies.include?(company) to false i get the form, but nothing updates.

EDIT 2 -

```
class Employmentship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessor :company_id, :user_id
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is you employmentship model? has_many_through is for going through another model.

Comment: WOW, you definitely pointed to the right direction.  Had employmentships insteas of employmentship in my model name.  But still not creating the relationships.