# rails 3 has_many :through Form with checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Asked similar before.

[Rails 3 has_many :through Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054337/rails-3-has-many-through-form)

But can't get the relationship with employmentships to be created from the users form.

Have read http://www.justinball.com/2008/07/03/checkbox-list-in-ruby-on-rails-using-habtm/
 and http://millarian.com/programming/ruby-on-rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/ (which I was really hoping that it worked.)

Form submits, but only creates a blank record in employmentship.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
...
<p>
   <% Company.all.each do |company| %>
        <%= check_box_tag :company_ids, company.id, @user.companies.include?(company), :name => 'user[company_ids][]' -%>
     <%= label_tag :companies_ids, company.id %>
   <% end %>
</p>
<p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I think that the first arg of the check_box_tag function is the actual name of the input, so instead of

```
check_box_tag :company_ids, company.id, @user.companies.include?(company), :name => 'user[company_ids]'
```

you could try something like

```
check_box_tag 'user[company_ids]', company.id, @user.company_ids.include?(company.id)
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: I though the same in the beginning, but it was correct.  Based on Millarian's example, my problem was that I had @user.attributes = {'company_ids' => []}.merge(params[:user] || {}) in the wrong place in my controller.  For me it was before if @user.update_attributes(params[:user]) on update and before if @user.save on create.

Comment: There is a way to use `f.check_box ...` ?

Comment: if you have multiple check boxes, make sure the first arg is 'user[company_ids][]' so that form names are unique. Else it will just take the last check box value.

Comment: I could not get around the "just take(s) the last check box value" issue using any syntax provided - or get it to save "all unchecked" by any of the hidden_field tricks scattered about. I wound up just manually assembling tag-values in the controller.  But if anyone reading this is on Rails4, I am now using a much easier way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339869/rails-4-checkboxes-with-a-has-many-through

Answer (score 15):

Include a hidden field tag in the form to make sure something gets submitted when none of the check boxes are selected. This should work, after the <%end%>:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "user[company_ids][]" %>
```

Comment: This is a good way of handling the "no checkboxes selected" use case.  Many of the examples on handling multiple checkboxes on a has_many :through relationship fail to mention this.