# Rails 3 Many.to.many association, issues about controller and view

Tags: model

I've two models "Projects" and "Hardwares" that has a many to many relatioship between them. Those are codes for Hardwares and Projects models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :hardwares
end

class Hardware < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :projectes
end
```

I've done tests using rails console, but I'm new to Rails and I've difficulties with controller and view. My issues are the following: I need a simple view for Projects that allowed me to add hardwares to it and I don't know in witch way I can do it :(
Anyone can help me or suggest basic examples sites that I can use?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using `users` and `languages`. It has the migrations, views, models, and controller code.

> http://www.justinball.com/2008/07/03/checkbox-list-in-ruby-on-rails-using-habtm/

Also, this rails cast might be pretty helpful if you prefer video format:

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes

And here are some additional links you may find helpful:

- http://dabrorius.com/ruby-on-rails-tutorials/rails-many-to-many-association-tutorial/
- http://ramblings.gibberishcode.net/archives/rails-has-and-belongs-to-many-habtm-demystified/17

Comment: Do you think that first link that you post can be useful also for Rails 3.1 ?I'm working on this version.

Comment: Yes, still works with one small tweak http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054633/rails-3-has-many-through-form-with-checkboxes

Comment: As a further comment to your question, the API for habtm hasn't really changed since any of those tutorials were released. Really you're question is about the structure of the controller and view which can be found there

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this revised [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised) from Ryan Bates, a pure genious.