# Rails - Dynamically add form fields and converting params in "array"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, viewparams

I would like to add dynamically new input (select) field, this is ok and done by JQuery, but when passing to the controller `create` it keeps only the first entry.

This is my `new.html.erb` view

```
<%= simple_form_for @comp, :url => url_for(:controller => 'competitors', :action => 'create'), :method => 'post' do |f| %>
    <div id="form_inputs">
        <%= f.error_notification %>
        <br />
        <%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.order("LOWER(name) ASC"), :id, :name, :prompt => "Select an user", required: true %>
        <span class="label label-important"><%= f.error :user_id %></span>
        <br />
        <%= f.collection_select :competitor_id, Company.order("LOWER(name) ASC"), :fb_id, :name, :prompt => "Select a competitor"%>
        <span class="label label-important"><%= f.error :competitor_id %></span>
        <br />
    </div>
        <div class="add">Add another competitor <%= image_tag "add.png" %></div>
        <br />

    <%= f.button :submit, "Create new competitor!" %>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".add").on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $("#form_inputs").append("<%= escape_javascript(f.collection_select :competitor_id, Company.order('LOWER(name) ASC'), :fb_id, :name, :prompt => 'Select a competitor') %> <span class='label label-important'><%= escape_javascript(f.error :competitor_id) %></span><br /> ");

        $('select').selectpicker();
    });

</script>

<% end %>
```

The params that I would like to recieve in my controller is something like this:

`params[:user_id]` => OK
`params[:competitor_id]` => an array of all IDs that the user has inserted (can be only 1 or +).

For example, if the user "clicks" three times the add buttons, there are 4 `competitor_id` and the `params[:competitor_id]` should be something like:
`params[:competitor_id] = [71,32,65,234]` in the order of selects.

How can I convert the various `:competitor_id` selects in one array?

Comment: I'd suggest `competitor_ids` instead. See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054633/rails-3-has-many-through-form-with-checkboxes

Comment: @damoiser what is that you can do with `multiple => true` options something like this  `<%= f.collection_select :competitor_id, Company.order("LOWER(name) ASC"), :fb_id, :name,:multiple => true%>`

Comment: thanks both for the suggestion, I'd try the @Zenph suggestion but with no success (seems that I can't do a "pluralize" and again the model of competitor is simples an association 1-1 to an user and a competitor); then I'd try with :multiple as Viren suggests, but nothing changes (tried different combination but not renders any multiple attribute in html)

Comment: @damoiser what happen to ur html code after u did `multiple => true` because the way I knew it would give you a tag with name like this `competitor_id[]` resulting in passing multiple selected value in the as only select box that is render

Comment: @Viren nothing happens, that's the problem. I have read, like you say, that a tag name like competitor_id[] must be showed, but it's not my case (maybe because I use selectpicker from bootstrap? That rewrite partially the select input code).

Comment: @damoiser I dont feel that way that a js plugin would change the behavior of the collection_select did u blindly copied my code because I just give you a prespective I wasnt sure abt the correct syntax