# rails 3, uninitialized constant Tercero::terceroclasificacion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i update class_name

/models/tipotercero.rb

```
 class Tipotercero < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_many  :terceroclasificaciones   
   has_many :terceros , :class_name => "Terceroclasificacion"
 end
```

/models/tercero.rb

```
class Tercero < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ciudades
  has_many :terceroclasificaciones
  has_many :tipoterceros, :class_name => "Terceroclasificacion"
end


class Terceroclasificacion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tercero
  belongs_to :tipotercero
  attr_accessor :tercero_id, :tipotercero_id
end
```

/views/terceros/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
    <% for tipotercero in Tipotercero.all %>
    <div>
      <%= check_box_tag "tercero[tipotercero_ids][]", tipotercero.id, @tercero.tipoterceros.include?(tipotercero) %>
      <%= tipotercero.nombre %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

the error is

```
uninitialized constant Tercero::terceroclasificacion
```

I have tried to follow the post
[Rails 3 has_many :through Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054337/rails-3-has-many-through-form) but I could not find the error in my application

add terceros controller

/controllers/terceros_controller.rb

```
class TercerosController < ApplicationController
  # GET /terceros
  # GET /terceros.xml

  def index
    @terceros = Tercero.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @terceros }
    end
  end

  # GET /terceros/1
  # GET /terceros/1.xml
  def show
    @tercero = Tercero.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @tercero }
    end
  end

  # GET /terceros/new
  # GET /terceros/new.xml
  def new
    @tercero = Tercero.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @tercero }
    end
  end

  # GET /terceros/1/edit
  def edit
    @tercero = Tercero.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /terceros
  # POST /terceros.xml
  def create
    @tercero = Tercero.new(params[:tercero])

  #  @tercero.attributes = {'tipotercero_ids' => []}.merge(params[:tercero] || {})

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tercero.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@tercero, :notice => 'Tercero was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @tercero, :status => :created, :location => @tercero }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @tercero.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /terceros/1
  # PUT /terceros/1.xml
  def update
    @tercero = Tercero.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tercero.update_attributes(params[:tercero])

        format.html { redirect_to(@tercero, :notice => 'Tercero was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @tercero.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /terceros/1
  # DELETE /terceros/1.xml
  def destroy
    @tercero = Tercero.find(params[:id])
    @tercero.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(terceros_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

edit 3

the page error is:

```
NameError in Terceros#new

Showing /home/andres/desarrollos/rubyonrails/proyecto/app/views/terceros/_form.html.erb where line #92 raised:

uninitialized constant Tercero::terceroclasificacion
Extracted source (around line #92):

89:    <div class="field">
90:     <% for tipotercero in Tipotercero.all %>
91:     <div>
92:       <%= check_box_tag "tercero[tipotercero_ids][]", tipotercero.id, @tercero.tipoterceros.include?(tipotercero) %>
93:       <%= tipotercero.nombre %>
94:     </div>
95:     <% end %>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/terceros/new.html.erb
```

4 edit

error to create tercero is:

```
NoMethodError in TercerosController#create

undefined method `type_cast' for nil:NilClass
Rails.root: /home/andres/desarrollos/rubyonrails/proyecto

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/terceros_controller.rb:44:in `new'
app/controllers/terceros_controller.rb:44:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"tercero"=>{"identificacion"=>"1110465574",
 "empresa"=>"hogar",
 "tipo_identificacion"=>"2",
 "direccion1"=>"dierccion",
 "nombre"=>"carlos andres",
 "direccion2"=>"123",
 "ciudad_id"=>"2",
 "telefono_fijo"=>"132233",
 "telefono_movil"=>"123123",
 "fecha_nacimiento(1i)"=>"2013",
 "observaciones"=>"",
 "fecha_nacimiento(2i)"=>"10",
 "fecha_nacimiento(3i)"=>"17",
 "representante_legal"=>"",
 "tipotercero_ids"=>["1",
 "2",
 "3"],
 "apellido1"=>"colonia",
 "apellido2"=>"riveros",
 "pagina_web"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Crear Tercero",
 "authenticity_token"=>"SeUoILctpNr9t6Lx8wSoHVTO5mjk0qJfnzJsb9Jtzao=",
 "utf8"=>"âœ“"}
```

Comment: the error is not in the piece of view code you have shown

Comment: 1. When did you get an error? Show entire error. 2. Show view file for action wich cause an error, not just a partial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes other model cannot be derived from the association name just by Rails conventions and such strange errors occurs. You can pass class name like this:

```
has_many  :terceroclasificaciones, :class_name => "Terceroclasificacion"
```

And btw, you can make your life easier just by using English names for your models and stuff. You do localization in your view anyways.

Comment: you are right..thank so much but, Now show me 
#<Tipotercero:0xb5e63d6c>#<Tipotercero:0xb5e63d1c>#<Tipotercero:0xb5e63c7c> with checkbox any idea ?

Comment: No problem - you can click on a tick on my answer, making it green ;) As for you second question try defining to_s instance method in your model, returning name / title / or whatever you got there :)

Comment: excuses, i not undertand how to instance method in model :(

Comment: Well, read this and tell me if it was any helpful: http://www.aimred.com/news/developers/2008/10/05/dont-forget-about-to-s/

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this

```
attr_accessor :tercero_id, :tipotercero_id
```

I think you want it to be an `attr_accessible` but not `attr_accessor`