# rails saving has_(and_belongs_to_)many relationship using :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So i want to save a HABTM relationship but i have extra field on my model so i'm usign has_many and through method.
Here's my models:

```
#project_task.rb
class ProjectTask < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :description, :name, :user_id, :project_id, :user_ids
   belongs_to :project
   belongs_to :user #Created by

   has_many :project_task_users #Here is the HABTM
   has_many  :users, :through => :project_task_users #AND HERE

   validates :name, :presence => true
   validates :project_task_users, :length => { :minimum => 1} #must have atleast 1 record in the HABTM relation
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_task_users
end

#project_task_user.rb
class ProjectTaskUser < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :project_task
end
```

My form:

```
        <p>Users:</p>
        <% for user in @users %>
            <div>
              <%= check_box_tag "project_task[user_ids][]", user.id, @task.users.include?(user) %>
              <%= user.name %> - <%= user.company.name %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
```

My controller:

## GET

```
def new_task
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = ProjectTask.new(:project_id => @project.id)
    @users = @project.users
end
```

## POST

```
def new_task_post
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = ProjectTask.new params[:project_task]
    @task.user_id = current_user.id
    if @task.save
      redirect_to @project
    else
      @users = @project.users
      render action:"new_task"
    end
  end
```

When i submit, the `@task.save` returns false and the errors array with the `project_task_users` validation

## Update

as Pablo89 pointed out i renamed my check_box_tag to this
`<%= check_box_tag :user_ids, user.id, @task.users.include?(user), :name => 'project_task[user_ids][]' -%>`
and it saves only if i comment out the validation. How should i validate that a user is selected while creating a project_task?

Comment: Which are the errors? I think the error may be in `<%= check_box_tag "project_task[user_ids][]", user.id, @task.users.include?(user) %>`, because of the name, I will checkout... If you comment the validation of `project_task_users`, does it save the data with no `project_task_user`? (Also you can use nested models...)

Comment: I got `Project task users is too short (minimum is 1 characters)` because it does not detect the users association.
Yes, if i comment out the validation it does save w/o users

Comment: Add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_task_users` in the `project_task.rb`

Comment: Did.. but same validation errors (check the update)

Comment: I was checking this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054337/rails-3-has-many-through-form and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054633/rails-3-has-many-through-form-with-checkboxes, check the answer of this last one, see the sintaxis of the checkbox, try it, hope it helps